# JQuery UI sortable: restore position based on some condition

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I call `sortable.stop()` to make an ajax call to store some data after drag & drop operation.

When the ajax call returns an error (application logic error or net problem) I want to move the dragged element to its original/start position, how can I achieve it?

The scenario should be

1. user drags A to B
2. the `sortable.stop()` event is called, it triggers an ajax call
3. the ajax call returns an error
4. inside the `stop()` event we get the ajax error
5. move A to its original position
6. user again move A to B
7. everything is ok
8. A remains in its new position in B

Steps 6-8 are shown to clarify a successive drag can be done and previous error must be forgotten.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Have a look at [`.sortable('cancel')`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-cancel); something like this:

```
var list = $('#some-list')
list.sortable(
{
    // Some options.
    stop: function()
    {
        $.post('some-url', someData, function()
        {
            if (somethingWentWrong)
            {
                list.sortable('cancel');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Under the stop() callback it doesn't work so I've used receive() instead of stop() and canceled drop with $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');

Comment: this worked for me and saved me some hassle. I didn't need to use @dafi code but glad I know it now! :)

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to **dafi** - this works for me:

```
$('#some-list').sortable({
  // other options here,
  receive: function(event, ui) {

    // ajax or function here
    if(somethingWentWrong) {
       $(this).sortable('cancel');
       $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
    }

  }

 });
```

I'm not sure if you need `$(this).sortable('cancel');`, but I figure it's best to cancel the source *and* the destination sortable lists. This way the list item reverts immediately. Other Sortable [options](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#options) here.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, liveat60fps , its the second statement out of the two which you only need.

```
$('#some-list').sortable({

      // other options here,
  receive: function(event, ui) {

    // ajax or function here
    if(somethingWentWrong) {
       $(this).sortable('cancel');
       $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
    }    
  }    
});
```

This way on a certain condition, you can revrt back to the orignal state.