# Reordering ul elements in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQuery UI sortable: restore position based on some condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661514/jquery-ui-sortable-restore-position-based-on-some-condition)

I am running into a small problem. I am using the sortable plugin in Jquery UI to do "mass" reordering. However, I want to allow the user to "cancel" all the reordering he has done. I already have an "initial" order saved into the `<li>` element via HTML5. Therefore, I am trying to get the list back in order according to what the initial "order" was. However, nothing appears after this function call... I don't want to just replace the inner-html as I want to keep the "data" data associated to each LI.

```
    function reverseBackCellsOrder(line) {
        var vals = {};
        var count = 0;
        var ul = $("#"+line+"-ul-sortable .sortable-items-"+line);

        ul.each(function (index){
            vals[$(this).data("order")] = $(this)[0];
            count++;
        });

        for(var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            ul[i] = vals[i];
        }
    }
```

EDIT #1:
Sorry for the "vagueness" of this description. I just looked at the variables after the function gets called, and the "ul" elements holds the re-ordered elements as I want them to be, HOWEVER, they do not appear properly on the page. As if it "needed" a repaint.

Comment: actually what information the line variable holds. here.. please be specific when you ask.. or give a jsfiddel link

Comment: Yeah what is the error / etc happening here? This is very specific, yet vague about certain things. Elaborate more and maybe someone can help!

Comment: I would just store references to the li elements in the correct order prior to any ordering being done. You can then simply append them in the correct order on demand. http://jsfiddle.net/DsYfa/

Comment: @KevinB wow... that worked. But, I don't understand how when I am about to re-append the originalOrder, if I check the "ul" length in Chrome, it went from 7 to 0. Then I append and it goes back to 7. Where did all of them go?!

Comment: @abisson I don't understand, can you demonstrate in the fiddle where that happens?

Comment: @KevinB when you are at     ul.append(originalOrder);... how come it doesn't add 10 "MORE" li to the end? You didn't clear the ul, yet, there is always only 10.

Comment: because i'm appending the same elements that are already there. I'm simply moving them from their current location to a new location.

Comment: Perfect! Do you want to add your solution as an answer? I'll approve it!